# Effectful service can not find context-bound implicit monad instance

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scala-cats, side-effects

I am not yet super strong with the concept of effects, so some of my assumptions might be completely wrong. Please correct me whenever you see such occurrences.

I am building an application (not from scratch, but rather developing the skeleton) with scala-cats and cats-effects. The main class extends `IOApp` and starts a web server:

```scala
object Main extends IOApp {

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    new Application[IO]
      .stream
      .compile
      .drain
      .as(ExitCode.Success)

}

class Application[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect: Timer] {

  def stream: Stream[F, Unit] =
    for {
      // ...
    } yield ()

}
```

This is the first encounter with the `F[_]` type. The `: ConcurrentEffect: Timer` context-bound says that there are two instances declared *somewhere*: `ConcurrentEffect[F[_]]` and `Timer[F[_]]` if I understand that correctly.

Skipping the HTTP layer of application, route handler uses the service I am trying to implement with two different variations - `DummyService` and `LiveService` - `Dummy` is supposed to always return the constant (dummy) data, whilst `Live` one sends a REST request and parses the JSON response to internal domain models:

```scala
trait CurrencyConverterAlgebra[F[_]] {

  def get(currency: Currency): F[Error Either ExchangeRate]

}

class DummyCurrencyConverter[F[_]: Applicative] extends CurrencyConverterAlgebra[F] {

  override def get(currency: Currency): F[Error Either ExchangeRate] =
    ExchangeRate(BigDecimal(100)).asRight[Error].pure[F]

}

object DummyCurrencyConverter {

  // factory method
  def apply[F[_]: Applicative]: CurrencyConverterAlgebra[F] = new DummyCurrencyConverter[F]()

}
```

So far so good. The only bit of mystery to me is why we have to have that `Applicative` implicit.

But now I try to implement the `Live` service which will also make use of the `Cache` (to throttle the requests):

```scala
trait Cache[F[_], K, V] {
  def get(key: K): F[Option[V]]

  def put(key: K, value: V): F[Unit]
}

private class SelfRefreshingCache[F[_]: Monad, K, V]
(state: Ref[F, Map[K, V]], refresher: Map[K, V] => F[Map[K, V]], timeout: FiniteDuration) extends Cache[F, K, V] {

  override def get(key: K): F[Option[V]] =
    state.get.map(_.get(key))

  override def put(key: K, value: V): F[Unit] =
    state.update(_.updated(key, value))

}

object SelfRefreshingCache {

  def create[F[_]: Monad: Sync, K, V]
  (refresher: Map[K, V] => F[Map[K, V]], timeout: FiniteDuration)
  (implicit timer: Timer[F]): F[Cache[F, K, V]] = {

    def refreshRoutine(state: Ref[F, Map[K, V]]): F[Unit] = {
      val process = state.get.flatMap(refresher).map(state.set)

      timer.sleep(timeout) >> process >> refreshRoutine(state)
    }

    Ref.of[F, Map[K, V]](Map.empty)
      .flatTap(refreshRoutine)
      .map(ref => new SelfRefreshingCache[F, K, V](ref, refresher, timeout))

  }

}
```

Here, `SelfRefreshingCache` requires `Sync` instance to be present - otherwise I am getting an error saying it is not defined when trying to construct a `Ref` instance. Also, in order to be able to use the `state.get.map(_.get(key))` statement in the `SelfRefreshingCache` class, I have to use the `Monad` constraint, presumingly to tell Scala that my `F[_]` type inside `Cache` can be `flatMap`-ped.

In my `Live` service I am trying to use this service as follows:

```scala
class LiveCurrencyConverter[F[_]: Monad](cache: F[Cache[F, Currency, ExchangeRate]]) extends Algebra[F] {

  override def get(currency: Currency): F[Error Either ExchangeRate] =
    cache.flatMap(_.get(currency))
      .map(_.toRight(CanNotRetrieveFromCache()))

}

object LiveCurrencyConverter {

  def apply[F[_]: Timer: ConcurrentEffect]: Algebra[F] = {
    val timeout = Duration(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

    val cache = SelfRefreshingCache.create[F, Currency, ExchangeRate](refreshExchangeRatesCache, timeout)
    // ---> could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type cats.Monad[Nothing]

    new LiveCurrencyConverter(cache)
  }

  private def refreshExchangeRatesCache[F[_]: Monad: ConcurrentEffect](existingRates: Map[Currency, ExchangeRate]): F[Map[Currency, ExchangeRate]] = ???

}
```

Currently, I am stuck at getting compilation error saying I don't have an instance of `Monad[Nothing]`. And this is where my whole story `Main` turns around: if I understand the whole concept behind type constraints (requiring implicits to be defined in the scope of a method call), then the `F[_]` type should be propagated from the very `Main` level down to my `Live` service and should be something like `IO`. And `IO` has both `map` and `flatMap` methods defined. On a `Live` service level, the `refreshExchangeRatesCache` makes a REST call (using the `http4s`, but that should not matter) and is supposed to run on something like `IO` as well.

First of all, are my assumptions about context boundaries and `F[_]` propagation from the `Main` class correct? Can I then hide the `IO` type on the `Live` service level? Or how do I provide the required `Monad` implicit instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is the first encounter with the F[*] type. The :
>   ConcurrentEffect: Timer context-bound says that there are two
>   instances declared somewhere: ConcurrentEffect[F[*]] and Timer[F[_]]
>   if I understand that correctly.

To be specific, it has to be declared inside the [implicit scope](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html).

> The only bit of mystery to me is why we have to have that Applicative
>   implicit.

You need evidence of an `Applicative[F]` because your method uses `pure[F]` to lift 
`ExchangeRate` onto `F`, where `pure` is defined in the `Applicative` typeclass:

```
ExchangeRate(BigDecimal(100)).asRight[Error].pure[F]
```

> Also, in order to be able to use the `state.get.map(_.get(key))`
>   statement in the SelfRefreshingCache class, I have to use the Monad
>   constraint

Since you're using `.map` and not `.flatMap`, it will suffice to require an instance of `Functor` and not `Monad` for the class definition of `SelfRefreshingCache`. For the companion object, you'll need a `Monad` in order to `flatMap`.

> First of all, are my assumptions about context boundaries and F[_]
>   propagation from the Main class correct?

Yes, they are. When you build your entire program in `Main`, and "fill in" `IO` where `F[_]` is required, the compiler will search for the existence of all the implicit evidence required from IO in scope, given that you've captured the requirements from each method invocation using context bounds or plain implicit parameters.

> Can I then hide the IO type on the Live service level?

The `IO` is hidden in your approach, as `Live` only knows the "shape" of the type, i.e. `F[_]`. Requiring the immediate solution to your problem, the previous answer has stated you need to add `F` to your method call in order for the compiler to infer which type you meant to fill in `refreshExchangeRatesCache`.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer and referring all my questions!

Answer (score 0):

Add the type information, in this case F, to the line

```
val cache = SelfRefreshingCache.create[F, Currency, ExchangeRate](refreshExchangeRatesCache[F], timeout)
```

Comment: Well, that solves the *immediate* problem but raises another few - Scala could not find implicit `ConcurrentEffect[F]`. That's why I am asking if my assumptions around `F[_]` type propagation and context boundaries are correct

Comment: I haven't gone through your entire code. But its simple, if you are calling a method which requires certain conditions to be met, at that point of calling you should tell the Scala compiler that I will make sure that the F will meet those requirements. That means for the above code it should not throw could not find implicit `ConcurrenEffectt[F]` since the caller, here the `apply` method says the F is of `ConcurrentEffect[F]`